# iOS App Admob text and image banner distribution

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, admob

There are 2 types of admob banners, image banner and text banners.

for image, I only need to click once to get paid.

But for text banner, if I use old SDK, you only need to click once on the arrow icon (on the right hand side). But if I use the newest SDK, even if you click on the arrow icon, the icon just turn to "View" button. You can only get paid if user click on that button. This is not user friendly, since people do not like to click twice, and precisely. And this may reduce ads income.

My question is, is it possible to do one of the following:

1. only receive image banner
2. modify it to be like old SDK, just click once to get paid. I can't use the old SDK since it uses UDID (admob says). And admob may stop providing ads to old SDK soon. Admob stopped ads for SDK before 2011, and my SDK is 2011
3. What is the distribution of image and text banners. Do you receive all image banners in one geo area and text in the other, or do you receive all image banners on one day and text on the other. What's the percentage of these 2 banners.
4. any other ways to solve it?

Note: I use adwhirl and admob. I don't use Admob mediation.

Comment: Shouldn't you grant the bounty to @EricLeichtenschlag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is not possible to request only specific formats at this time. You can only control category filters.
2. There is no API in the new SDK to enable a 1-click through to ads.
3. Not sure of the distribution. The types of ads being served to certain locations depends on where advertisers choose to run their text/image campaigns.

The idea behind the two-click mechanism is to prevent accidental clicks. In the long term it should increase conversion rates and make advertisers more confident in advertising more and bidding higher for the legitimate clicks. It also is a better experience for your users. If they intend to click on an ad and click the "View Ad" or Download button area of the ad on the first press, they'll get taken straight to their destination.

Also, even on image ads, if you click near the border of the ad, there is a confirmation overlay for the user to actually click through.

NOTE: AdWhirl vs. AdMob Mediation has no effect on this behavior.